# error in the firebird request: invalid token alter

Tags: sql, firebird

the error in line 5, I understand it's a syntax error, but I don't understand how to fix it

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger ustroystva row position bi for ustroystva
active before insert position 0
as
if(exists (select * from ustroystva where table_name="ustroystva" and column_name="rowposition")) then
alter table ustrovstva drop rowposition;
end 
else then
alter table dbo.ustroystva add rowposition int null
end
```

Comment: This is not the code you're trying to execute on Firebird, otherwise you'd get a "Token unknown - line 1, column 36; row".

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you show isn't even valid in Firebird, it seems to be some amalgam of Firebird and Microsoft SQL Server syntax. If executed on Firebird it will result in a different error than you mention in your question. The error would be:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 1, column 36
-row
```

And that is because it doesn't follow the [`CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-trgr-crtalter) syntax of Firebird.

However, looking at your intent, the problem is that you're trying to execute DDL (`ALTER TABLE`), and you cannot execute DDL in triggers (or any other PSQL code). There are workarounds for this, using [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-execstmt), but it is not recommended to do that, and it will likely fail because the table is in use.

Also, the DDL you're trying to execute doesn't even make sense to me. For every insert into `ustroystva` you either drop the column `rowposition` or add it. Consider carefully what you're trying to do and why.